# Optimize date index to convert to the day of the week

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I want to convert the `date index` of the `dataframe` to the day of the week. I have tried many methods. First convert the `date index` to a `column`, then convert the `column` to `datetime`, and then use the `datetime.dt.dayofweek` method to convert it to weekdays. The code is as follows, How to optimize?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

d = pd.date_range('1/1/2020', '12/31/2020').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

data = np.random.rand(len(d)) * 100
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=d)

df['weekday'] = df.index
df['weekday'] = pd.to_datetime(df.weekday).dt.dayofweek
```

Comment: why not use a DatetimeIndex?

Comment: I tried it, it seems that I am using the wrong method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` on returns of `pandas.date_range()`, you are changing the `DatetimeIndex` type to string. Your target format `%Y-%m-%d` is actually the same with default format, you needn't do this. Here is an example:

```py
d = pd.date_range('1/1/2020', '12/31/2020')

data = np.random.rand(len(d)) * 100
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=d)

df['weekday'] = d.dayofweek
# or
df['weekday'] = df.index.dayofweek
```

BTW, in your code, you can do in one line like

```py
df['weekday'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index).dayofweek
```

Comment: If I don’t use `.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`, in pycharm, when I use `view as dataframe`, the index will be displayed as `2020-01-01T00:00:00.00000000`, I just want to display the index as `2020-01-01`, can it be done?

Comment: @jaried Seems not. An issue 4 years ago: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-25291.

Comment: Thank you, I think the display should not affect the use.